# [Proof Verification]Is my proof for the following statement on closed sets correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$. Let $L$ be the set of all limit points of $A$. Then $L$ is closed.

*Proof:* We need to show that $L$ is closed, ie. it contains all its limit points. Let $x$ be a limit point of $L$. Then by definition $x \notin V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap L$ where $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ is the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$. We now need to show that $x \in L$. Suppose $x \notin L$. Then choose an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $y \in V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A$ and $y \neq x$. Then $x$ is a limit point of $A$, but we have arrived at a contradiction, so it must be that $x \in L$ and hence $L$ is closed.

Comment: Two different epsilon’s is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something odd where you say "Then by definition $x\not \in V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap L$ where $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ is the $ϵ$-neighborhood of $x$".

First, by definition, $x$ is a limit point of $L$ if and only if for *every* $\epsilon>0$, the intersection $V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap L$ is non-empty. When you say *the* $ϵ$-neighborhood it seems as if you were fixing an $\epsilon$ and then saying stuff about it. With this being understood, the relation $x\not \in V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap L$ doesn't have anything to do with the definition of being a limit point of $L$. Even more, we can deduce from $x\not \in V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap L$ that $x\not\in L$, and that's exactly the opposite of what you want.

Whenever you try to show that something is closed, it is better almost every time to prove that the complement is open. Having this in mind, take a point $x\not\in L$ (i.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus L$). By definition, there exists $\epsilon>0$ in such a way that $V_\epsilon(x)\cap L=\emptyset$. Then, we infer that $V_\epsilon(x)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$. Thus, since $x$ was an arbitrary point in the complement $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$, the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$ is open and so, $L$ is closed.

**Edit (proof with accumulation points):** Take a point $x\not\in L$ (i.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus L$). By definition, there exists $\epsilon>0$ in such a way that $\left( V_\epsilon(x)\setminus \{x\} \cap L\right)=\emptyset$. Then, since $x\not\in L$, we get that $V_\epsilon(x)\cap L=\emptyset$ and so, $V_\epsilon(x)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ that is contained in $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$. Thus, since $x$ was an arbitrary point in the complement $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$, the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$ is open and so, $L$ is closed.

Comment: Doesn't the definition of a limit point include the fact that the set $V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap L$ be non-empty as well as not include $x$? That's what I mean by the statement $x \notin V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap L$.

Comment: There are various notions of "points". I like to distinguish between "limit points" and "accumulation points" (Wikipedia says they are the same). The definitions I'm working with are the following: $x$ is a *limit point* of a set $B$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, $V_\epsilon(x)\cap B\neq \emptyset$; $x$ is an *accumulation point* of a set $B$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$, $\left(V_\epsilon(x)\setminus \{x\}\right) \cap B\neq \emptyset$. With either definition, the proof I gave above to check that $\mathbb{R}\setminus L$ is open works, with a slight modification with a. point.

Comment: @Peluso: That’s a non-standard definition of *limit point*; I strongly advise avoiding it, as it is extremely likely to be misunderstood. The proper statement in that case is simply that $x\in\operatorname{cl}B$, $x$ is in the closure of $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. What is the correct term for points in the closure of a set? Cluster points?